# iOS control to choose value by typing

Tags: ios, user-interface

I have a list of people and user should choose one. There are about 100 persons, so it is pain for user to scroll `UIPickerView`. I need to give user ability to type some letters to decrease number of choices. Many environments have control like textbox with drop-down, so you can filter values by typing. How to do that in iOS?

I use core data

Comment: Are you using Core Data or not?

Comment: yes, It is core data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link `<UITextFieldDelegate>` or `<UISearchBarDelegate>` in header file. Set your `UITextField` or `UISearchBar`'s delegate to self.

Add its delegate methods:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

or

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

And call your own core data search method:

```
- (void)searchFor:(NSString *)searchString
{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"wHaTeVeR contains[c] %@", searchString];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"wHaTeVeR" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];

    NSError *fetchError = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];
```

This will look for words containing your searchString. Hope this leads you in the right direction. :)

Comment: Thanks. So, I need to fetch objects and display some kind of suggestion for user, right? It is so strange there is no ready-to-use view for this, because I believe many people need it.

Comment: Well yes, get the `objects` in an array of dictionaries and return the results with a block or however. Then you populate a tableview with the results. Like this: http://s12.postimg.org/qmo5rk4zh/image.png

Comment: I have a form with several ``UITextField``s. Looks like I need to display controller modally with searchbar and table over my form when user taps one of fields. Is it a thing that is called "Search Bar and Search Display Controller" in Story Board?

Comment: I dont know storyboard, but yes SearchBar or TextField. You dont have to make it another controller. I just display a tableview ontop of my controller and hide it when i dismiss keyboard..